# PHP solution: I have a page that I get with post but need to delay some code until the page has posted - codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, post

I know the title is confusing but I don't know any way to briefly describe this:
Basically I have a web page that I get from a button, when the button is pressed certain data (a unique identification name) gets submitted to the page I want to view, and the page views, but because it is technically always request_method = post then when I submit data on the form from the page I want to view, I want the UID to stay, but it doesn't because it gets refreshed, if I am being unclear don't flag the post, be clever and ask for more information you need.

here is relevant code:

my controller:

```
public function clist() {
        $this->load->model('list_model');
        $fields = $this->list_model->listcliname();
        $data = array();
        $data['fields'] = $fields;
        $this->load->view('clientlist', $data);

    }
    public function clistedit() {
        $uid = $_POST['UID'];
        $data2 = array();
        $data2['uid'] = $uid;
        $this->load->view('clientlistedit', $data2);
        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {

            $client = array (
            'UID' => $uid,
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'address' => $_POST['address'],
            'telephone' => $_POST['telephone'],
            'fax' => $_POST['fax'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'mobile' => $_POST['mobile'],
            'contact' => $_POST['contact']
            );
            $this->load->model('list_model');
            $this->list_model->editcli($client);

        }
        else {
        $this->load->model('list_model');
        }
    }
```

My view where I post the original data:

```
        <form action="clistedit" method="post">
        <button name="UID" type="submit" value="<?php echo $field['UID']?>">edit</button>
         </li>
         </ul>
         <?php
    }


?>
```

My view that the page goes to when I gather the next set of data:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
    ?>
     <form action="/clientlist/clistedit" method="post">
name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php ?>"><br>
Contact: <input type="text" name="contact" value="<?php ?>"><br>
Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php ?>"><br>
Telephone: <input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php ?>"><br>
Fax: <input type="text" name="fax" value="<?php ?>"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php ?>"><br>
Mobile: <input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php ?>"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="<?php return $uid;?>">
</form>
<?php
```

Does anyone have a solution for my problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<input type="submit" value="<?php return $uid;?>">` to

`<input type="submit" name="UID" value="<?php echo $uid;?>">`

and you should be fine.

BUT, since you don't want the submit button to display as a button with a number on it, you'll be best off doing this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="UID" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Whatever you prefer it to say" />
```

This will achieve the same result, without having to change anything else.

Cheers -!

Comment: Woah thanks! :) is there a way to do it where the button doesn't actually show the uid? I'm supposing not as it displays the value it is sending but just a query.

Comment: Haven't seen this kind of mistake in long, nice catch.+1

Comment: @seanyt123 - OH yeah - my bad, i forgot about that -  Here, I'll edit the answer, accordingly --

Comment: On a side note, instead of `<?php echo $uid; ?>`, you can `<?=$uid ?>` - which is a bit neater. Some hosting companies don't allow that short tag, but most do --